# scanf() giving wrong output for last line of input

Tags: c++, input, scanf

I am using scanf to take input for a graph. The input is as follows :

```
8
1 2
3 3 5 6
2 4 7
2 3 8
2 1 5
1 7
2 6 4
0
```

The first integer (8) is the number of vertices, followed by 8 line. The first integer in each is the number of outgoing edges from vertex 1 in the first line, vertex 2 in the second line and so on.

The function i have written is as follows :

```
void getInput() {
    //init();
    int numVertex; int numTest;

    scanf("%d", &numVertex);
    for(int i =1 ; i <= numVertex;i++) {
        int ver,nC; vector<int> vList;
        //fscanf(file,"%d", &ver);
        scanf("%d", &nC);

        for(int j=0;j<nC;j++) {
            int temp ;
            scanf("%d", &temp);
            vList.push_back(temp);

        }
        props pr = {-1,-1 , vList};
        graph.insert(make_pair(i, pr) );
    }
}
```

However, the output for the last line of my input becomes weird and it basically repeats the last digit of its previous line multiple times. For the above input , the output I am getting :

```
1 : 2
2 : 3 5 6
3 : 4 7
4 : 3 8
5 : 1 5
6 : 7
7 : 6 4
8 : 4 4  // this is where it should give nothing
```

Can anyone tell me whats going wrong here? The exact same sequences of conversions, when I convert to taking input through file gives me the right output.

Can someone please point me to any error?

Comment: Could you please clarify your input format? Currently it's not clear where are your line separators. It's also not entirely clear what's your output supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
if (scanf("%d", &nC) != EOF) {

    for(int j=0;j<nC;j++) {
        int temp ;
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        vList.push_back(temp);

    }
    props pr = {-1,-1 , vList};
    graph.insert(make_pair(i, pr) );
}
```

This will check if the read was successful. The repetition of the last line of input is a well known issue and occurs because the last read attempt fails (because end of file has reached) and `scanf` returns the same result as its previous call.

Comment: I think it should not be compared with EOF, but with the number of fields expected - in this case 1. The same in second scanf.

Comment: For the issue mentioned, which is repetition of *last* line, end of file error is the most common problem. Hence the use of EOF.

Comment: The check I proposed will verify that condition too.

Comment: Yup, so its basically the same thing (in this situation) :)

Comment: @SidharthMudgal The EOF condition is also giving me the same error. Just to be clear, the content of the second last line's last field is getting repeated in the last line .

Comment: Have you tried doing `if (scanf("%d", &nC) == 1)` as EFraim mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

What is `props`?

Whatever it is, doing C-style struct initialization on something containing an std::vector is asking for trouble - the results are undefined and almost surely not what you want.

Your input code seems OK though, despite lack of error-checking as noted in another answer.